# Kitchen sink relocation

Tags: plumbing

I am remodeling a kitchen for a customer and they would like to relocate their sink across the kitchen which is a little over 10’ away.

Is this acceptable with all the bends that would be needed to vent sink at its new location?

Comment: Clearly not DIY if you are being paid by the home owner.  10 feet away does not tell us much about what is between the new location and the old.  What bends?

Comment: Can the vent go up and out from the new sink location, or is that not an option?

Comment: The main vent line is on the other side and there is no way I can run new line on new location. If anything I was thinking of going up to the ceiling over about 10 ft and tap into original vent pipe lotta work though.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a commercial job, not DIY.